# How to find a list that only contains a certain field and no other fields?

Tags: c++

How to find a list that only contains a certain field and no other fields?
eg：

```cpp
[a, b, c, d]
[a, b, c]
[a, b]
```

find the list containing only a and b: `[a, b]`

Comment: Read entire line into `std::string`, then count commas. More than 1 comma, can't be it. When only one comma found, check `string[1]` and `string[4]`.

Comment: What container are you using? Can the list be in a different order? (`[a, b]` required but there's a `[b, a]`) which works)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have implemented what you need. The `input` is 2d vector, which contains the input that you have mentioned as three lists. The `check` vector contains the list which you want to check if exists in the input.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<vector<char>> input = {
        {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
        {'a', 'b', 'c'},
        {'a', 'b'}
    };
    bool broke = false;
    vector<char> check = {'a', 'b'};
    sort(check.begin(), check.end());
    for(int j=0; j<input.size(); ++j){
        auto x = input[j];
        if(x.size()!=check.size())continue;
        sort(x.begin(), x.end());
        for(int i=0; i<min(x.size(),check.size()); ++i){
            if(check[i]!=x[i]){
                broke = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!broke){
            cout<<j+1<<" number list is equal to required list\n";
        }
        broke = false;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code accepts dynamic input so you can play around with input and check values to understand code. I have implemented ways suggested by Cwift in previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. Compare with input's size
2. Sort input's list and every list you have
3. Compare every index of your list with input's list

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list<char> list[] = { { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' },
                          { 'a', 'b', 'c' },
                          { 'a', 'b' } 
                        };

    for (int i = 0; i < list->size(); i++)
    {       
        if (list[i].size() == 2 && 
            find(list[i].begin(), list[i].end(), 'a') != list[i].end() && 
            find(list[i].begin(), list[i].end(), 'b') != list[i].end())
        {
            cout << "Index: " << i << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "No required list." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there is more then one solution to this task.
A possible solution could be the following.

```
if (list.length() == 2 && list[0] == a && list[1] == b)
{

}
```